# How to make div visible only in particular devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap technology .

How can i show any div tags only for specific devices like i want to show a div to be visible only in laptop but not in desktops

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Answer (score 1):

You can't set something visible only for laptops but not in desktops. You can declare media-queries, so you can decide if something is visible on specific resolutions. For example mobile devices use screen size width 320px.

More about media queries --> [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Bootstrap documentation --> [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to do that. For example a phone has a high pixel-ratio so you could add this for high-res phones:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* STYLES */
}
```

you can find more useful information about media queries [here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/), [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/media-queries/) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)